# Python/Django - CoInitialize has not been called

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to open, refresh and save excel via win32com.client.Dispatch but I keep running into error that
`CoInitialize has not been called.`

In my function I have run `pythoncom.CoInitialize()`
but it did not help. I've tried to look for different solutions found here on site but none solved it.

I am additionally getting error in pycharm about wrong reference

```
Cannot find reference 'CoInitialize' in 'pythoncom.py'
```

I have `import pythoncom`

Actual code

```
    def refresh_excel(self):
        path = 'my_excel.xlsx'
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()  # I have tried removing this line as well but with no effect
        xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application', pythoncom.CoInitialize())
        workbook = xl.Workbooks.open(path)
        .
        .
        .
```

Code stops at `xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application',pythoncom.CoInitialize())`

Comment: TBH, I am unclear when the 2nd parameter to `Dispatch()` should be used. What happens if you leave it out? You need the CoInitialize if your code is not running in the main application thread.

Comment: I will get the same error.